# where is my __dict__? Class inherited from a namedtuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I inherit a class from a namedtuple, why the `__dict__` is empty? Here are minimal codes prepared to show. You can see that `x.__dict__` is empty, but `z.__dict__` has the information.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name age')

class Student(Person):
    def print(self):
        print(self.name)

x = Student("Tom",25)

class Employee:
    def __init__(self,name, age):
        self._name = name
        self._age = age
y = Employee("Jerry",24)

class MyEmployee(Employee):
    def print(self):
        print(self._name)
z = MyEmployee("John",22)


print(x.__dict__)
print(y.__dict__)
print(z.__dict__)
```

Here is the output

```
{}
{'_name': 'Jerry', '_age': 24}
{'_name': 'John', '_age': 22}
```

Comment: The attributes as part of a namedtuple are not stored in `__dict__`

Comment: A namedtuple doesn't *need* a `__dict__` - everything gets stored in elements of the underlying tuple.

Comment: One reason to use `namedtuple` is to avoid the overhead of a `__dict__` attribute.

Comment: It still looks weird. As you can see that the `x` is empty, but we can print `x.name`?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking? ``__dict__`` is an implementation detail of certain types – notably not of tuples and named tuples – and not requires for attributes to exist. Consider a completely virtual attribute ``property`` backed by ``def name(self): return "James"``.

Comment: Named tuples are internally represented as sequences, not hashtables. You can use the `_asdict()` method to get a dictionary of the attributes if you need one. If you just need to dynamically access attributes by name, `getattr` is easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: Tuples do not need `__dict__` to store values. By default, inheriting from a `type` class (including `object` and `tuple`) adds a `__dict__` however.

---

The `__dict__` is an implementation detail used by certain types of objects to store attribute values. Notably, tuples do not use `__dict__` to store their values:

```py
>>> joe = ("Joe", 24)
>>> joe[0]        # values available as item
"Joe"
>>> joe.__dict__  # no dict for values
...
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

As the name implies, `namedtuple` are kind of tuples and as such also do not have `__dict__`. Their attributes are merely aliases to index-lookups, pointing to the same value.

```py
>>> jane = namedtuple("Person", ["name", "age"])("Jane", 24)
>>> jane[0]        # values available as item
"Jane"
>>> jane.name      # values available as item alias
"Jane"
>>> jane.__dict__  # no dict for values
...
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

---

The `__dict__` attribute is commonly added by the act of *inheriting* any `object`. One must define explicit `__slots__` to prevent this.

```py
>>> # base object has no __dict__
>>> object().__dict__
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute '__dict__'
>>> # inheritance adds __dict__
>>> class ObjectWithDict(object): pass
>>> DictObject().__dict__
{}
>>> # __slots__ prevent adding __dict__
>>> class ObjectWoDict(object): __slots__ = ()
>>> ObjectWoDict().__dict__
AttributeError: 'ObjectWoDict' object has no attribute '__dict__'
>>> # inheritance adds __dict__ – even to __slots__
>>> class ObjectMaybeDict(ObjectWoDict): pass
>>> ObjectMaybeDict().__dict__
{}
```

*The `x.__dict__` comes from inheriting `Student` from `Person`.* It contains no data, since that is already handled by the underlying tuple.

One can understand how `Student` works by emulating it via inheriting from `tuple`, aliasing fields via `property`, but not preventing the creation of `__dict__`.

```py
>>> class Person(tuple):
...     # no __slots__ -> a __dict__ is added
...     @property
...     def name(self):     # attributes are aliases ...
...         return self[0]  # ... to items in the tuple
...     @property
...     def age(self):
...         return self[1]
...     def __new__(cls, name, age):
...         return super().__new__(cls, (name, age))
...
>>> jimmy = Person("Jimmy", 12)
>>> jimmy[0]    # item access as expected for tuple
"Jimmy"
>>> jimmy.name  # attribute access – that we implemented as item access
"Jimmy"
>>> jimmy.__dict__
{}
```

Comment: Thanks! But this raised another question, what can be a base class? If  "By default, class adds a __dict__ however.", it means that namedtuple is not a class, but why it can be a base "class" here?

Comment: @drbombe I have changed the wording a bit to avoid confusion. The ``class`` *keyword* by default results in the addition of ``__dict__`` – that is actually encoded in the underlying invocation of a metaclass, so it is neither a hard rule nor easy to explain completely. Things can still be classes if they do not include a ``__dict__``, e.g. ``ObjectWoDict`` in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

In short: there isn't one to begin with. You can test it by checking `Person("Alice", 21).__dict__` or even just `("Alice", 21).__dict__`, and you will see that both of them raise `AttributeError`. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/12d0a7642fc552fa17b1608fe135306cddec5f4e/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L403) of `namedtuple`, you will see that the construtor (`__new__()`) of a `namedtuple` is identical as that of a `tuple`. And if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/12d0a7642fc552fa17b1608fe135306cddec5f4e/Objects/tupleobject.c#L780) of `tuple.__new__`, you will find that no `__dict__` has ever been created.

The empty dict you see comes from the fact that you subclassed a `namedtuple`. The later two were populated inside your `__init__` functions. But since nothing is done during your initializer in your `Student` class, its `__dict__` is empty.